# Carrying Liquor from Germany to India

Tags: transit, germany, india, alcohol, duty-free

I will be traveling from Frankfurt to Bangalore and I have my transit at Mumbai. I would like to get some good liquors back home. So, what would be the safest (security check wise) mode to carry liquor? I am worried about Mumbai to Bangalore transit, as it would be a domestic one and I wouldn't want my purchase to be thrown away by airport security officers.

Comment: You won't get blind from any of these so I suspect that's not what you meant by *good*. It's a matter of your taste (or those you make a present) and a matter of the region you visited in Germany. Makes no sense to bring e.g. Aquavit if you had been in Bavaria and don't like caraway. – Typical for Germany are *Obstbrand* and *Kräuterlikör*. There are hundreds of different brands and flavours. But don't export Jägermeister yourself – it's available everywhere already.

Comment: How much are you planning to buy, bearing in mind import limits / customs duties? Your options to carry liquids are probably limited to packing the bottles in your checked luggage.

Comment: Can I buy the liquors(1L) from duty-free stores either at Frankfurt/Mumbai and carry it all the way to Bangalore as my hand luggage?

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten one bottle of liquor when flying in to India from Frankfurt in the past, and never had any problems with this.

That was one of the only few items I got, and it was well below the monetary duty limit and the 2 litre alcohol limit:

You can find the limits [here](http://www.indembassyuae.gov.in/docs/trvler-guide_ason05feb2015.pdf).